# PHP POST array is empty after data is posted through ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I've a simple select which on change posts data through ajax. On the same page I want to get the data from POST array but the post array is empty. This is the code.

**Javascript**

```
$('.product-selectbox').change(function() {
    var select_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var presentkort_type = $(this).val();
    presentkort_type = presentkort_type;
    alert(presentkort_type);
    //alert("id is "+id);
    var request =  $.ajax({
        url : "cashregister",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            prod_id : select_id, presenkort : presentkort_type
        },
        dataType : "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        $('#data').html(select_id);
        console.log(select_id);
        console.log(presentkort_type);
        location.reload(true);
    });
    request.fail(function(msg) {});
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['prod_id'])) {
    $product_id = (int)$_POST['prod_id'];
    print "product id is ".$product_id;
} else {
    print "no data";
    $product_id = (int)$_POST['prod_id'];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you open the console in your browser and monitor the status of the XHR request. Ensure that the relative URL you're specifying exists on your server yoururl.com/cashregister . On chrome press Ctrl+Shift+I to open the console, then go to Network->XHR

Comment: The url exists, I can see the data if I log it to console. but the POST array on the page is empty.

Comment: Do a series of `var_dump()` on your PHP side for `$_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST` to see what is being sent.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when I was posting an object to my server as well. It turned out that my content was actually be passed in the request body.

To access the content I had to use the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This allowed me pull the object out of the request body and placed it in a usable variable that I could manipulate.

Here is the reference I used: [PHP Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: I scratched my head with this too - sending ajax requests from an angularjs/cordova android app this is the only way to get at the vars.

Answer (score 0):

remove datatype as html ,it should be like this

```
 var request =  $.ajax({
        url : "cashregister",
        type : "POST",
        data : {prod_id : select_id, presenkort : presentkort_type}
    });
```

and check that select_id is coming or not by alerting it

Comment: thank you gautam for your reply. Now it reloads the page but POST is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

remove DATATYPE as html and submit full form.

```
$j.ajax({
      url: '/cashregister/',
      type:'POST', 
      data:$j('#Id').serialize(),
      success:function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
      }
```

Note: #Id : form id

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it was down to the `max_input_vars` setting in the `php.ini` file. I found I was sending a lot more than 1000 variables - upped it to 5000 and it worked.